# How to place a header image above body image

Tags: html, css, image, header

Here's what it currently looks like:

[image]

What's supposed to be the header is currently transparent over the body image. I'm trying to get it to sit behind where it says "NEWS" at the top. The header image is currently inserted with `<img src="https://i.imgur.com/wLTnUyF.png">` and I don't know what to add to reposition it.

(I can also add additional details if this isn't enough to get the answer I'm looking for.)

**Edit**: Here's the whole code: [PASTEBIN](https://pastebin.com/ETrxtANA)

Comment: you can use z-index

Comment: Post more code please

Comment: can you add html code too? also try to add a working Snippet with StackO. or [http://jsfiddle.net/](http://jsfiddle.net/)

Comment: @MarcHjorth I added the rest of the code. Sorry- I knew I didn't add enough but I didn't know what other points would be worth mentioning.

Comment: @Vishnuprasad The "skin header" section only accepts HTML, so yes.

Comment: provide the HTML too. make a jsfiddle or a codenpen...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```css
* {
  background: transparent;
  border: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.gr1,
.gr2,
.gr3,
.gr-top .tri,
.gr-top .gr h2 img,
.gr-top .gr span {
  display: none;
}

.gr-top .gr {
  padding-left: 0 !important;
}

/* body { background-image: url('https://i.imgur.com/iYr6KIy.png'); background-repeat: no-repeat; background-size: 950px 540px;  } */

h3 {
  font-size: 25px;
  text-align: center;
  color: #c8b46e;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 400px;
  background-position: center center;
  padding: 20px;
  background-image: url("https://i.imgur.com/RbBgBbv.png");
}

.scrollbox {
  height: 360px;
  width: 420px;
  overflow: auto;
  padding: 20px;
  font-family: Ubuntu;
  font-size: medium;
  color: #aaa89e;
  background: transparent;
}

.scrollbox2 {
  height: 100px;
  width: 360px;
  overflow: auto;
  padding: 20px;
  font-family: Ubuntu;
  font-size: medium;
  color: #aaa89e;
  background: transparent;
}

.gr-body .gr .grf-indent .text {
  max-width: 500px;
}

.gr-body .gr .grf-indent .bottom {
  position: relative;
  bottom: 160px;
  left: 10px;
  color: #fff;
}

.gr-body .gr .grf-indent .bottom a {
  color: #fff;
}
.gr-body .gr .grf-indent .bottom a:hover {
  color: #c8b46e;
}

a:hover {
  cursor: url(https://i.imgur.com/dg8PzHg.png), pointer;
}
body {
  cursor: url(https://i.imgur.com/dg8PzHg.png), pointer;
}

.container {
  position: relative;
}

.bottomleft {
  position: relative;
  top: 60px;
  left: 10px;
  font-size: 18px;
}

.topright {
  position: relative;
  bottom: 444px;
  left: 510px;
  font-size: 18px;
}

.top {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  width: 500px;
}

img.back {
  margin-top: 70px;
  width: 940px;
  height: 540px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>
    <div class='wrap'>
        <h3>NEWS</h3>
        <img class="top" src="https://i.imgur.com/wLTnUyF.png">
        <img class="back" src="https://i.imgur.com/iYr6KIy.png">



    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you are trying to do. But if you are trying to add an image to the header, you should do:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<header>

<img src="https://i.imgur.com/wLTnUyF.png">

</header>
<body>

<img src="bodyimage.png">

</body>
</html>
```

If that doesn't work, remember to actually download the image and upload it into your workspace.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up figuring up a way to get the results I wanted.
What I did is I added a background specifically to `.gr-top .gr h2` and then change the alignment on the text.
Now my journal skin looks like this ; [Updated Preview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/agrhw.png)

```
.gr-top .gr h2{
text-align: right;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-position: left left;
padding: 33px;
background-size: 600px;
background-image: url("https://i.imgur.com/wLTnUyF.png");
}
```

Sorry for the bad phrasing on the question. I'll try to be clearer next time.